# startActivity does not work after passing data from current activity into new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

```
 public void DoneBtnClicked(View v) {
        if (mCameraData != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowResultCamActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("jmxs.utrack.camera_data",mCameraData);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "No Camera Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Hi, Im creating a camera app and in the code above is a fuction that is called after an image is taken and I want to pass that image to a new activity to process it.

**mCameraData** is byte[].

**Problem**: startActivity(intent); doesnt work.

**Tried**: I can pass an INT and it works but when i tried to pass byteArray or bitmap it doesnt.

Is it because of the size?

Comment: how large is your data? the limit is less than 500 kb

Comment: `after an image is taken and I want to pass that image to a new activity to process it` - solve this headache by using one Activity, and multiple fragments.  Android isn't mean't to pass Bitmaps around using Intents, it can, obviously, but shouldn't be relied upon as a tried and tested method ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit to the size of data that can be passed through an intent. The limit is [roughly 500Kb](https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit) - most photographs will be larger than this.

Consider saving your image to a file location, passing the URI to the receiving activity and loading it within there.